# c# bad request 400

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

So.. am trying to connect to an api thats using client id - app-id - app-key

it's working in postman as header and i set it up as inheriting auth from parameter

and i added it to the header .....

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error:     (400) Bad Request.'

how can i use that in mvc c#
```

giving me error 400

```
====================================
[HttpPost]
public void Drivere(tripelm trips)
{
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
client.BaseAddress = newUri("https://***********v2/");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Basic");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client-id", "*******DD0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("app-id", "*******");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("app-key","2aa****d4ad");


//HTTP POST
var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<tripelm>("trips", trips);
postTask.Wait();

var result = postTask.Result;
if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
// return RedirectToAction("Index");
}}

================================
```

response is

```
Result = {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: '', Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Expect-CT: enforce,max-age=30
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=157680000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
```

Comment: could u pls show us how you call the api vai postman? A screenshot is good and you can hide the provide information

Comment: you can check it now ....... thnx

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, and I want to confirm with you that if it's required to add `Authorization` into your request since in the screenshot, there's no `Authorization` http header. And by the way, I want to know if there's CORS issue in your app. Did you add [cors policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware) in your startup.cs?

Comment: oh o seems i did not O_O

Comment: yeah.. pls try to add the cors policy and try again, kindly let me know if it worked or not, thanks.

Comment: A "Bad Request" means that some part of the request is wrong. without knowing the API or the spec, anyone can only really guess what could be wrong. You should probably talk to whoever supplies the API instead.

Comment: here is the code and could not add cors thing ....

Comment: pls check the content in your question....@ABDULLAHMAKKI

Comment: i don't get what youo mean?

Answer (score 0):

fINALLY WORKING NOW

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(client.BaseAddress.ToString());
            var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<tripelm>("trips", captainTrip);
var xresult = postTask.Result; 


var result = postTask.Result;
if (xresult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
                
string x = "Nice";
}
```